# Where should I put the Meteor subscription in a tracker-react container?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Using Meteor 1.3, I have a react component wrapped with tracker-react. I set it up like the example on [tracker-react github](https://github.com/ultimatejs/tracker-react#implementation)

```
class TaskIndex extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      subscription: {
        tasks: Meteor.subscribe("tasks", Meteor.userId() )
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.state.subscription.tasks.stop();
  }

  getTasks() {
      return  Tasks.find().fetch()
  }

  render() {
   //... displays the tasks
  }

}
```

The subscription passes the current user to get the right tasks. The problem is, when I logout, and Meteor.userId() becomes undefined, the subscription is not updated. The tasks stay visible until I refresh the page. The reverse is true when I login: no tasks appear when Meteor.userId() becomes valid.

If instead I put the subscription in the getTasks() method as below, it behaves correctly, but feels wrong. Should the subscription be in one of the lifecycle methods? How do I stop the subscription, do I even need to?

```
  getTasks() {
      Meteor.subscribe("tasks", Meteor.userId() );
      return  Tasks.find().fetch()
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer courtesy of the author on [github issues](https://github.com/ultimatejs/tracker-react/issues/18)

> Hey, yes, that is because it is in the constructor, which is run once
>   before the component is mounted. If you want to have a subscription
>   that is reactive while the component is rendered, it needs to be in
>   the render block.

... or in some function that is called by the render block.

```
render() {
   Meteor.subscribe("tasks", Meteor.userId() )
   return (
      // some jsx
   )
}
```

Comment: a nice addition to this might be:   `sub(){
    const subscription  = Meteor.subscribe("pub",Meteor.userId());
    return {ready: subscription.ready(), data: Data.find({}).fetch()};
  }`

Comment: But this way you cannot stop the subscription, which AFAIK will create memory leaks, no?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following to update a subscription based on the actively signed in user. I honestly always had the same question you have, and could never find an "official" answer.

```
var userIdTracker;

class TaskIndex extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

    constructor() {

        super();

        userIdTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
            this.setState({
                subscription: {
                    tasks: Meteor.subscribe("tasks", Meteor.userId())
                }
            });
        });

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Make sure you stop the autorun or it will continue to exist
        userIdTracker.stop();
        this.state.subscription.tasks.stop();
    }

    getTasks() {
        return  Tasks.find().fetch()
    }

    render() {
        //... displays the tasks
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't `TrackerReact` superfluous, here? Since you have `Tracker.autorun`, there is no need to have `TrackerReact` as well.